# changing record in view via helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes, view, instance-variables

I'm pretty sure that this is a newbie question. I have a users `show.html.erb` that displays room attributes like: `<%=@room.greeting%>` and `<%=@room.main_text%>`.

Now all I want to do is change the `@room` instance variable when the user presses a button. Simple? - I did think that.

After spending many hours on the internet I have put the following in the `show.html.erb`

```
<%= navigation_helper("The Marsh") %> # the Marsh is a room
```

then I put the following into the helper method

```
def navigation_helper(params:name)
  link_to "Back Out", users_navigation_path(@name )
end
```

then I put the following into the users controller

```
def navigation(params:name)
  @user.room_name = Room.find_by_name(params:name)
end
```

And in the routes file:

```
get 'users/navigation'
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: Sorry. I am trying to allow the user to change the instance variable via a button and then the attributes will be displayed to reflect the changes and it will be as if the user has entered another room

Comment: This means that you need to do a round trip back to your server. Because, once the user sees your form, rails application finished rendering user's page. You'd have to create an action that changes and shows a changed state, not a helper.